# Sonos album Art Size in presentation map

Tags: sonos

Can someone explain how to configure the Sonos Presentation map to adjust ArtSize URI via the pmap. Our base URL is:

http://....../load_albumart.php?album_id=12&size=200

I do not understand how to configure the pmap to replace 200 in 600 for example.

Answer (score 2):

The PresentationMap for Album Art works like a regular expression. When the controller wants an image that is 200x200, it will search the `albumArtUri` element and replace the string you configure as a size `substitution`.

In your case you have these URLs based on your example:

- http://.../load_albumart.php?album_id=12&size=200
- http://.../load_albumart.php?album_id=12&size=600
- http://.../load_albumart.php?album_id=12&size=XXXX

Your presentation map will then identify the substitution rules for each resolution. In your case, something like:

```
<PresentationMap type="ArtWorkSizeMap">
  <Match>
    <imageSizeMap>
      <sizeEntry size="200" substitution="size=200"/>
      <sizeEntry size="600" substitution="size=600"/>
      <sizeEntry size="XXXX" substitution="size=XXXX"/>
    </imageSizeMap>
  </Match>
</PresentationMap>
```

And your default SMAPI response that contains an `albumArtUri` would include a default size like so:

```
<trackMetadata>
  <albumId>12</albumId>
  <duration>253</duration>
  <artistId>artist0001</artistId>
  <artist>Saratoga Indiana</artist>
  <album>Forgiveness & Gratefulness</album>
  <albumArtUri>http://.../load_albumart.php?album_id=12&size=200</albumArtUri>
</trackMetadata>
```

In this scenario, if the controller has a hi-resolution display (E.g. Retina or xhdpi), the controller will then use the presentation map to load the highest resolution image that makes sense by replacing the substitution from the resolution the controller wants (identified by the `size` attribbute in a `sizeEntry` node) with the resolution the `trackMetadata` (or `mediaMetadata`) has in the `albumArtUri` node.

There is a short [tutorial available on the Sonos developer website](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/366) that has more details.

Also, while I realize you are probably using 200 and 600 as example resolutions, please note Sonos asks for a specific set of resolutions (`sizeEntry` elements with specific `size` attributes) that work best on the various controller platforms. Those resolutions are described in the tutorial.

Although you may not offer all resolutions in Sonos' preferred list, the controller will take the next largest size in the configuration. E.g. Sonos asks for a 180x180 image. In this example, the controller would select the `200` pixel configuration as the next highest resolution above 180. For 300x300 and 600x600, the controller would use the `size="600"` `sizeEntry`.